# 3 column responsive footer

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, multiple-columns

I have a responsive grid layout for thumbnail images and a full width header. It is built using 'ul' and 'li' to make the grid. So basically I'm not using a responsive grid layout throughout. Although I would like to have a three column footer at the bottom that is responsive (stack on top of each other)

I want the first column to align full left and the other two columns to align right. each column is only around 15% of the total width (so i couldn't just have all three width 33%) I want the functionality of a three column layout like in many of the themes like skeleton boilerplate, etc

I am having trouble making a good css markup that will work, I have used...

css

```
F1 {
padding: 15px;
width: 100px;
margin: 0 0 0 20px;
float: right;
}

.F2 { 
float: left;
text-align: left; 
}

.F3 { 
font-size: 13px;
text-align: right;
float: right; 
}
```

but that just separates the divs, and doesn't offer much control

any help or references to help are greatly appreciated

Comment: Please Show us your HTML Markup and create a http://jsFiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly, the following can work. Shown with divs, but a ul & li structure would work as well.

HTML:

```
<div class="footer">

  <div class="f1">first left</div>

  <div class="f2">middle right</div>

  <div class="f3">last right</div>

  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.footer {

   text-align: center;
   width: 100%;

}

 .f1 {

   background: green;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;

 }

 .f2 {

   background: pink;

 }

 .f3 {

   background: blue;

 }

 .f1,
 .f2,
 .f3 {

  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: right;
   font-size: 12px;
   padding: 0 8%;
   min-width: 300px;
   width: 33%;

 }

.f1 {

    text-align: left;

  }
```

If you set your divs to display inline-block with a min-width, on browser resize  the columns will begin to stack one on top of the other.

Alternatively, depending on styling, you might want to set them to inline-block without a min-width, and set a media query for them to display block on all screen sizes you want them stacked one on top of the other.

If you set box-sizing to border-box, you can add the necessary padding to the inside of the container to keep the content area around 15% of the total width.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It is much closer to what I want, only problem is as I mentioned I don't want to set the columns at 33%. because the content in each is small (makes the width of each like 15% of the page each) The first column will be on the far left. and the other two will be far right. having the middle and last div 33% will make a huge gap between them

Comment: Do you want your footer to span 100% width of the page?

Comment: yes. basically three columns, each has very little content so their widths are small. one aligns far left, the other two far right. (to the edges of the page when it is rescaled) even though they are small, their widths are still somewhat unknown. prob is I need more control (like two columns on right can have aligned right text, etc)